# How do I turn up logging verbosity for qmail?

Tags: email

Is there a qmail equivalent to sendmail's

```
define(`confLOG_LEVEL', `15')dnl
```

...and how would one figure out where it sent such logs to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The only way to get more verbose logging in qmail is to patch it.

As for where logs go, that's easy: they go to stderr. The DJB Way(tm) is to have multilog or svlogd attached to the stdout/stderr of qmail-send/qmail-smtpd and write the messages to files. Distributions sometimes try to shoehorn qmail into logging to syslog using various kludges, though.

When troubleshooting qmail, I've found that `strace` works well, especially if you know which component (`qmail-send`, `qmail-local` etc.) you're having a problem with. You can replace the internal components with shell wrappers that call the real program via something like `strace -ff -s200 -yy -o /path/to/strace.log $@`.

Comment: Marking as correct because qmail, dammit.